# cell validation using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am trying to assign a validation list to a cell. The validation list is variable depending on the value of a certain cell for example if the value if cell “C6” is 28 then the validation list shall be the range Sheet4.Range("b4:b20"). As you can see the validation list is from another sheet.in order to do this I wrote the below code

```
 ValrStart = Sheet4.Cells(rowno, 4).Address  ‘rowno is the row in which the validation list starts and its value comes from another part of the code 
ValrEnd = Sheet4.Cells(rownoEnd, 4).Address rownoEnd is the row in which the validation list ends and its value comes from another part of the code 
Rng = "Sheet4.Range(""" & ValrStart & Chr(58) & ValrEnd & """" & ")"
With Cells(20, 3).Validation
          .Delete
          .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
          Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Rng
          .ErrorMessage = "Invalid value. Select one from the dropdown list."
          check = Cells(20, 3).Validation.Value
          If check = False Then
          Cells(20, 3).ClearContents
          Exit Sub
          End If
        End With
```

What happens now is that what appears to me in the Cell is the value of the string Rng not the range that it represents.
Can anybody help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is in the `Formula1` parameter, which must have a "=" at its beginning

I'd have excel do the hard work for you like follows:

```
Dim rng As Range '<~~ set rng as of a Range type
With Sheet4
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(rowno, 4), .Cells(rownoEnd, 4)) '<~~ set rng to the wanted range
End With

With Cells(20, 13).Validation
    .Delete

    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & rng.Address(, , , True) '<~~ have Address function take out the correct formula, just add a "=" at the beginning

    .ErrorMessage = "Invalid value. Select one from the dropdown list."
    check = Cells(20, 3).Validation.Value
    If check = False Then
       Cells(20, 3).ClearContents
       Exit Sub
    End If
End With
```